# flutter - after swiched to master channel its showing error

Tags: flutter

I switched flutter to master channel to create bundle (flutter build appbundle)
but it's showing some error

Can you please help me on this?
Screenshot: **https://prnt.sc/qbeulk**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the bin/flutter file was corrupted due to permission issue. You may need to reinstall flutter SDK to fix the issue as your flutter bin file is missing.

Here is the installation manual: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install